# How to use nosetests in python while also passing/accepting arguments for argparse?

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py

I want to use `nose` and `coverage` in my project. When I run nose with `--with-coverage` argument, my programs argument-parsing module goes nuts because "--with-coverage" isn't a real argument according to it.

How do I turn the argparse off, but during testing only? Nose says all my tests fail because of the bad argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually just ran into this issue myself the other day. You don't need to "disable" your parsing module or anything. What you can do is change the module that uses `argparse` to ignore those arguments it receives that it doesn't recognize. That way they can still be used by other scripts (for example if your command-line call passes secondary arguments to another program execution).

Without your code, I'll assume you're using the standard `parse_args()` method on your `argparse.ArgumentParser` instance. Replace it with `parse_known_args()` instead.

Then, whenever you subsequently reference the parsed-arguments `Namespace` object, you'll need to specify and element, specifically 0. While `parse_args()` returns the args object alone, `parse_known_args()` returns tuple: the first element is the parsed *known* arguments, and the latter element contains the ignored unrecognized arguments (which you can later use/pass in your Python code, if necessary).

Here's the example change from my own project:

```
class RunArgs(object):
    '''
    A placeholder for processing arguments passed to program execution.
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        self.getArgs()
        #self.pause = self.args.pause  # old assignment
        self.pause = self.args[0].pause  # new assignment
        #...

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<RunArgs(t=%s, #=%s, v=%s)>" % (str(x) for x in (self.pause,self.numreads,self.verbose))

    def getArgs(self):
        global PAUSE_TIME
        global NUM_READS
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-p', '--pause', required=False, 
            type=self.checkPauseArg, action='store', default=PAUSE_TIME)
        parser.add_argument('-n', '--numreads', required=False, 
            type=self.checkNumArg, action='store', default=NUM_READS)
        parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', required=False,
            action='store_true')
        #self.args = parser.parse_args()  # old parse call
        self.args = parser.parse_known_args()  # new parse call
        #...
```

Answer (score 2):

I've read that you can use [nose-testconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig/), or otherwise use [mock](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/r9o2i/using_nose_and_argparse/c4439bd) to *replace* the call (not test it). Though I'd agree with @Ned Batchelder, it begs questioning the structure of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, instead of running nose with command-line arguments, you can have a [`.noserc` or `nose.cfg`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#basic-usage) in the current working directory:

```
[nosetests]
verbosity=3
with-coverage=1
```

Though, I agree that `parse_known_args()` is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for this method, @alecxe, I was wondering about nose configs myself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have tests that run your code, and then your code uses argparse which implicitly pulls arguments from sys.argv.  This is a bad way to structure your code.  Your code under test should be getting arguments passed to it some other way so that you can control what arguments it sees.

This is an example of why global variables are bad.  sys.argv is a global, shared by the entire process. You've limited the modularity, and therefore the testability, of your code by relying on that global.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful at a higher level. So is it foolish to write tests for the code that parses arguments? I guess it does seem redundant, since the arguments weren't intended to be permanent but just for use during development.

Comment: It's not foolish to test the code that parses arguments.  It's foolish that the code that parses arguments gets them directly from sys.argv.  It should parse a list of strings that you pass to it.  At the very top of your program, you can pass it sys.argv.  Then your tests can pass it different lists of strings, so that you can test different argument parsing scenarios.